# How do I create a Navigation Bar that has a left and right button on a ViewController that is not the root Viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

[image]

This is how I want it to look. I've tried to use this code:

```
let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
button.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "yourImageName.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(ViewController.callMethod), for:.touchUpInside)
button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30) 
//CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: button)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
```

However, when I create the Navigation Controller, I make my map view(the main screen) the root viewcontroller for the Nav Controller. Thus, the view will not have a default back button, since there are no views on the stack before it. Is there a way to override this so my image shows up for the left button? The code above does not produce an image for the left button successfully. It's blank.

Comment: Why init the UIButton with a type .custom?  I'm honestly not familiar with this UIButtonType but from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibuttontype) I think there's a chance that it has no appearance by default?  Maybe try .system instead.  Either way your code looks okay to me, have you tried using the view hierarchy debugger in Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer:

```
    var image = UIImage(named: "ic-menu-48px.png")
    let navCon = self.navigationController
    image = self.resizeImage(image: image!, targetSize: CGSize(width: 25.0,height: 25.0))
    image = image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style:.plain, target: nil, action: nil)


  func resizeImage(image: UIImage, targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let size = image.size

    let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / size.width
    let heightRatio = targetSize.height / size.height

    // Figure out what our orientation is, and use that to form the rectangle
    var newSize: CGSize
    if(widthRatio > heightRatio) {
        newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * heightRatio, height: size.height * heightRatio)
    } else {
        newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * widthRatio,  height: size.height * widthRatio)
    }

    // This is the rect that we've calculated out and this is what is actually used below
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)

    // Actually do the resizing to the rect using the ImageContext stuff
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
    image.draw(in: rect)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage!
}
```